# zend form is not being shown

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework

Hi I'm developing a PHP app and I'm using the Zend Framework and I'm new to it.

My problem is that I'm not able to print the form in the view. I've a file that contain the form, a controller that passes the title to the view and the view.

The view's title is displayed correctly but the form isn't being shown.

This is my code,

**FORM**:

```
class forms_UploadOtticaForm extends Zend_Form 
{ 
    public function __construct($options = null) 
    { 
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setName('contact_us');

        $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('title');
        $title->setLabel('Title')
              ->setMultiOptions(array('mr'=>'Mr', 'mrs'=>'Mrs'))
              ->setRequired(true)->addValidator('NotEmpty', true);

        $firstName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('firstName');
        $firstName->setLabel('First name')
                  ->setRequired(true)
                  ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $lastName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('lastName');
        $lastName->setLabel('Last name')
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $email->setLabel('Email address')
              ->addFilter('StringToLower')
              ->setRequired(true)
              ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
              ->addValidator('EmailAddress'); 


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Contact us');

        $this->addElements(array($title, $firstName, 
            $lastName, $email, $submit));

    } 
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
  class UploadOtticaController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
    function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->pageTitle = "Zend_Form Example";
    }
  }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<?php echo $this->pageTitle ;?>

<?php echo $this->form ;?>
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to instantiate the form in your controller, like this `$this->view->form = new forms_UploadOtticaForm()`? after the line where you've set the title.

Comment: i receive this error: Class 'forms_UploadOtticaForm' not found @deoliveiralucas

Comment: I am also new to zend-framework, but do you know you can make your form in HTML and you can also pass your data from controller to view through viewModel()..!